# No administrator rights on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: permissions

Please forgive me but I am new to Unbuntu.
I installed version 20.04 on a VM on my Windows 10 laptop. I am the only user but I am not administrator.

How can I resolve this to make myself an administrator?

Comment: Welcome. You should not become an administrator. You can perform administrative tasks with the `sudo` command, e.g. `sudo nano /etc/fstab`. Be very careful executing GUI stuff as administrator. Never, really never login as root user into the desktop environment since it is a serious security issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to elevate your privileges, you'll need the sudo command. You could alternatively log in as the root user, which I would highly not recommend. You could destroy your operating system by accident, so just stick with the first method. Try if it works by updating your packages:

```
sudo apt update
```

If you try this command without sudo, you should get an error message :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the exact problem wasn't exactly specified, here are some solutions on root and administrator permissions.

### Sudo

When running terminal commands but need admin permissions, use `sudo`. Example:

```
sudo apt update
```

### Sudo Su

You can also get permissions from `sudo su`. This will make your terminal window completely root.

**WARNING: It is dangerous to use `sudo su` unless you know exactly what you are doing.** If you accidentally do something wrong, you could hurt your system. Also, if you install some apps, those apps might only be available to root if you used `sudo su`.

### Administrator in File Manager

If you're using the `nautilus` file manager (you probably are, since it's the default file manager when instlaling Ubuntu), you can use the plugin `nautilus-admin`.

You can install it with `sudo apt install nautilus-admin`, which lets you right-click in the file manager and select "open as administrator."

Source: https://itsfoss.com/open-nautilus-as-administrator/